# Which program in ubuntu shows network usage at unity panel top-right beside the indicator?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

In my University Computer I saw a program in ubuntu which constantly monitored and displayed the network traffic(Download and Upload speed) in the top-left side ,at the indicator. But I couldn't get the name of that program. Can anyone tell me which program can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use `indicator-netspeed` to see the network traffic. You will have to add a new repository to install this. open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once its installed you have to log out and log back in. By default it shows the traffic of your wifi. You will have to change it to `eth0`if you are connected to the internet using ethernet.

You can also use `indicator multiload` to view a graph of your network usage.
you can install it using `sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload`. Once its installed you can open it from the dash. You may have to edit the preferences to see the network graph.

Comment: @user139820 Glad to help